# How to create margins when fetching text such as a description, from a database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, web

On my website, I am trying to fetch a description from a certain page, which works, but it just stays on one single line and you have to scroll sideways to read it. I want it to go up to a certain point and then go down a line, and repeat.  Thanks.

How can I put the code on here so that it just shows the code, and doesn't try to portray it?

Comment: Do you want to add your code to the question?

Comment: add your code here so that we can get more idea

Comment: copy your code and paste it

Answer (score 1):

You can use the php function [wordwrap](http://php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php).

```
echo wordwrap($description,75,"<br/>");
```

Alternatively you can put the element in a container with a fixed width.

```
echo "<p style='width: 400px;'>",$description,"</p>";
```

Comment: I keep getting this error from that   Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'width' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in /homepages/40/d462749961/htdocs/viewserver.php on line 35

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'width' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in /homepages/40/d462749961/htdocs/viewserver.php on line 35

Comment: updated ... this code should work from within a php code block

Comment: Now would that description in there be the row its taking the info from? Or do I keep the one I have?

Comment: it would be whatever you are outputting that is not wrapping like you want it to.

Comment: while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
  echo '
  <center><h2>'.$row['name'].'</h2> <img src= '.$row[banner].'> <br>
Posted by '.$row[user].'</center><br/>
  <table align="center">
  <tr>
  <td>IP:</td><td>'.$row[ip].':'.$row[port].'</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>Description:</td><p style='width: 400px;'>'.$row[description].' "</p>";
  </tr>
  </table>

Comment: change 'width: 400px;' to "width: 400px;"

Comment: No error, but its in the wrong place on the page (Not in the code) and not centered

Comment: You can see an example here  http://minecraft-serverlisting.com/viewserver.php?id=10

Comment: Also, as you can see, there are two extra " and one ;

Comment: in your code you have `<td><p style='width: 400px;'>'.$row[description].'</td></p>>` that should be `<td><p style="width: 400px;">'.$row[description].'</p></td>`

Comment: the sample data doesn't have anywhere to break the text so it's not going to wrap. One thing you can do is add `overflow:hidden` to clip off any data that flows outside of the box or `overflow:auto;` to give you scroll bars when needed.

Comment: for example `style="width: 400px; overflow: auto;"

Comment: Anyway to do it without any sideways scrolling? CLick that other link again to see how it is now.

Comment: change `$row[description]` to `wordwrap($row[description], 75, "<br/>", true);`

Comment: may have to tweek the 75 to make it wider or narrower

Comment: and drop the overflow:auto

Comment: if you like the width that it is now you want to change the 75 to somewhere arround 40

Comment: `<td><p style="width: 400px;">'.wordwrap($row[description], 40, "<br/>", true).'</p></td>`

Comment: on each of the `<td>`'s (not the `</td>`'s) change them to `<td valign='top'>`